# "take the form of direct attacks" VS "take the form of direct attack"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

This sentence comes from a GRE prep course:

> - As the creation of new knowledge through science has become institutionalized, resistance to innovation has become less aggreesive, taking the form of inertia rather than **direct attack**.

Since there would be many attacks from all around innovation, why would there is not a "s" after attack? Such as:

> - As the creation of new knowledge through science has become institutionalized, resistance to innovation has become less aggreesive, taking the form of inertia rather than **direct attacks**.

Comment: One could use the plural in this case, but it's not an error to use the singular.

Comment: I have reedited the post. Could it be ansered now? Why would both be okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example sentence is contrasting "inertia" with "direct attack" as different forms of resistance to innovation. In that sense, "direct attack" is used as the *method* by which resistance occurs, not as a reference to any specific attack (or attacks). Using direct attack *as a strategy* may involve one or more specific attacks.

Imagine this conversation between anti-innovation advocates:

> Alice: How do we best oppose innovation?
>
> Bob: By *direct attack*. (compare with: "by *force*" or "by *disinformation*")
>
> Alice: How would that work?
>
> Bob: We attack it in newspaper articles, TV ads, using school pamphlets, whatever we can come up with. The combined effect of all these *attacks* should tip the scales in our favor.

Answer (score 0):

Both usages would be correct- however, the way it is used depends on how many "direct attack(s)" there are.

Comment: (I'm new to this website, and I don't know what you mean by an answer drawing. Sorry. D:)

Comment: Welcome @bnicoleo0202! It just means that because Mike Philip has offered 50 points of his reputation as a reward for a good answer, the site is recommending that a good answer will be one that answers the question thoroughly, with multiple examples pulled (i.e., drawn) from credible sources. You may also want to check out the guide for new users, if you haven't already - https://stackexchange.com/tour   
  as well as our frequently-asked-questions:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites

Comment: To address the actual question though, I think it's a little deeper than the number of attacks. You're right that both forms are valid, but I would say that "...taking the form of inertia rather than direct attack" isn't talking about only one attack. It sounds to me more like it's describing the *style* of each attack, when it comes.